# Avoiding Repetitive View Code in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is for an ASP.NET MVC 4 application in a Razor view. I am passing a model to a partial view and am trying to iterate through a given list of properties contained in the model to be displayed as a table.

Given something like `List<string> propertyNames`, in this table, I would like to output the `DisplayNameFor` and the value of the property in a structure like so:

```
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model.property)</th>
    <td>@Model.property</td>
</tr>
```

I'll have to do this a few times in the partial because different properties correspond to different `div` elements in the partial where different tables will be inserted so I've created a helper and this is where I get hung up. First, the only way I know how to do this is reflection, and I have read that reflection is expensive especially for just doing one property at a time. Also, using this method, I can't get `@Html.DisplayNameFor` to work correctly because, using reflection, I don't quite know the syntax:

```
@helper IterateDetailPropertyNames(List<string> propertyNames) { 
    foreach (var property in propertyNames)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(Model, null));
                @*Error: Templates can be used only with field access, property access...*@
            </th>
            <td>
                @Model.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(Model, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

How can I make this work and improve this?

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[property]);` no reflection involved...

Comment: If your view is using a model, then you can use the `ModelMetadata` to access all the properties of the model, including its display name. Are you just wanting to display each properties display name and the property value in a table?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. That's pretty much the gist of it.

Comment: Then using the models `ModelMetadata` is the way to go. No time just now, but I'll add answer in 30 min or so. In the meantime, you might be interested in [this project](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-tablehelper) - have not go around to writing the docs yet, but that is described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A models `ModelMetadata` gives you the data you need to generate your table. It contains the model value in additional to properties such as the `DisplayName`, `DisplayFormatString`, `NullDisplayText` etc that are determined from annotations applied to your properties.

For more information of `ModelMetadata`, refer the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx) and [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 2: ModelMetadata](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html).

To generate your table, you could write the following `HtmlHelper` extension method

```
public static class TableHelper
{

    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayTableFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        // Get the ModelMetadata for the model
        ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        // Loop through the ModelMetadata of each property in the model
        foreach (ModelMetadata property in metaData.Properties)
        {
            var x = metaData.DisplayFormatString;
            string label = property.DisplayName;
            string value = null;
            if (property.Model == null)
            {
                value = metaData.NullDisplayText;
            }
            else if (metaData.DisplayFormatString != null)
            {
                value = string.Format(metaData.DisplayFormatString, property.Model);
            }
            else
            {
                value = property.Model.ToString();
            }
            TagBuilder labelCell = new TagBuilder("td");
            labelCell.InnerHtml = label;
            TagBuilder valueCell = new TagBuilder("td");
            valueCell.InnerHtml = value;
            StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
            innerHtml.Append(labelCell.ToString());
            innerHtml.Append(valueCell.ToString());
            TagBuilder row = new TagBuilder("tr");
            row.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
            html.Append(row.ToString());
        }
        TagBuilder table = new TagBuilder("table");
        table.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(table.ToString());
    }
}
```

and in the view

```
@using YourAssembly.TableHelper
....
@Html.DisplayTableFor(m => m)
```

You can also include the assembly in your `web.config` file so that the `@using` statement is not required in the view

As s side note, `<table>` elements are for tabular data and should not be used for layout. Instead consider using styled `<div>` elements

Comment: This got me really close so I really appreciate it. That's some pretty useful knowledge for the future too.